# What is Accelerate Polling in Heroku Connect?

Tags: heroku, salesforce, heroku-connect

What is the main purpose of 'Accelerate Polling' in Heroku Connect when mapping Salesforce objects to heroku.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Accelerate Polling**: Use this option  [refer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8XNn.png) if you need to sync changes instantly on change. This option should be enabled only if required in some scenarios.